# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using appDelegate for sharing NSMutableArray but it's crashing. Error message is:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

My code is:

```
countrydata *countryobj=(countrydata *)[listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(addItems==nil)
{
    addItems=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
[addItems addObject:countryobj];

callAppDelegate *appDelegate = (callAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.AddItems=addItems;

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Where is my code is wrong? appdelegate.AddItems is NSMutableArray and already declare in callAppDelegate.h. I already import callAppDelegate.h in top.

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? That error message means you are sending a message to an object which does not have that message declared. Possible memory leak with addItems there as well btw

Comment: appDelegate.AddItems=addItems; is error occur. I can't parse the value to appDelegate.

Comment: Your variable and class naming-"scheme" is really confusing. Some of your variables start with capital letters and some with small letters. The same applies to your class-names. This will get you in big trouble if your projects start to grow.

Comment: Totally agree with fluchpunkt, suggest you read some best practices about programming :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error occurred at appDelegate.AddItems=addItems then you might have forgotten to synthesize it.

You should add
`@synthesize AddItems;` 
after `@implementation` in your `*appDelegate.m`

This assumes that you've already declared it `@property (nonatomic, retain / assign)` in your header file (.h)

[update] Minor comment if you did declare it as `@property (nonatomic, retain)` then you should release `addItems` after setting it to a retained property because it will cause memory leak.

E.g.

```
appDelegate.AddItems=addItems;
[addItems release];
```